# Javascript how to parse csv to create new columns

Tags: javascript, csv, papaparse

I have a `.csv` with description strings in its rows, I need to parse their content but if there's a `\n` or `,` in it the parsing goes wrong.

With papa parse I can get headers and rows values in arrays, but then I need to parse the description value (`rowsId[4]`) and split it into columns.

`.csv` (exported from ecommerce):

```
    ID,COD,Name,Dscription,Meta
    1234,#324,box"<ul>
    \n<li>Dimensions: 37 x 45,5 x 203,5(h) cm</li>
    \n<li>made of wood</li>
    \n</ul>",789
```

Expected output:

```
rowId = [1234, #324, "box", "Dimensions: 37 x 45,5 x 203,5(h) cm", "made of wood", 789];
```

`.csv` (final)

```
    ID,COD,Name,Dscription1,Dscription2,Meta
    1234,#324,box,"Dimensions: 37 x 45,5 x 203,5(h) cm","made of wood",789
```

How can I split excluding the `\n` and `,` found between `" "` ?

Comment: I just tried demo from papa parse website, it will return data as an array of each line data. For your csv exported from ecommerce, it will return a length-5 array.

Comment: @MingzeLi It's true if you paste the code, if I upload the file it works. Still the problem persists when I need to parse it myself.

Comment: I tried to use this library locally and it works fine, if you want to remove those unnecessary code, can use "replace" with reg expression. Another finding is, if you want to remote the first line, simply add "header: true" so that the first line will be not parsed in data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for that:

```
let rawData = "<ul>\
    \n<li>Dimensions: 37 x 45,5 x 203,5(h) cm</li>\
    \n<li>made of wood</li>\
    \n</ul>"
 
console.log(rawData)

const regexp = /<li>(.*)<\/li>/g
const data = rawData.match(regexp).map(el => {
    return el.replace(/<\/?li>/g, '')
})

console.log(data)
// Array [ "Dimensions: 37 x 45,5 x 203,5(h) cm", "made of wood" ]
```